# Add training phrases in an intent

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I am trying to fetch list of already existing training phrases in an intent so that I can further add more training phrases in that list. But, `intent.getTrainingPhrasesList()` is returning `null` in my `java` code.

Here is my code:

```
List<TrainingPhrase> trainingPhrases = new ArrayList<TrainingPhrase>(intentinstance.getTrainingPhrasesList());
```

Can't understand why? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Could you post your concerned code and describe your problem a little bit more in detail? Thanks.

Comment: List<TrainingPhrase> trainingPhrases = new ArrayList<TrainingPhrase>(intentinstance.getTrainingPhrasesList());

Comment: I am trying to fetch list of already existing training phrases froma chosen intent